# Data validation on cells depending by the validated cell

Tags: excel, validation

I would like to apply validation data in Excel 2013 in the following case:
I have in A13 the sum of the values in A1:A12.
I would like to apply in the cells A1:A12 data validation such that A13<500.
I have tried to do it in the classic way, but I have the following problem: if, at the moment, A13 is, for example, 300, and I insert 230 in A7 (that was empty), if I type enter from my keyboard, I correctly get the error.
If I type 230 and, without typing enter, I click in any other cell, this value is accepted and A13 becomes 530.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I encountered your same error. i wonder if the event for leaving a cell by clicking is different to the event for hitting enter?

Comment: Can you please post the validation macro ?

Comment: It is not a macro, I did it without vba

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a couple of macros

```
Dim oldValue

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:A12")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If Range("A13").Value > 500 Then
                MsgBox "Error: A13 can not be greater than 500"
                cell.Value = oldValue
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Cells.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For you data validation ask for a number below:

```
=500+A1-SUM(A$1:A$12)
```

(for cell `A1` -- you can then easily apply that condition to the other cells)

Comment: Well, I could do even =SUM(A$1:A$12)<500, and it works great even if I click outside the cell.
Actually, this is an example for a very more complicated case where, however, there is this kind of dependency. For example, Sheet1!R10 depends on Sheet2!A23, Sheet2!A10 and Sheet3!B2. Each one of these three cells depend on other 10 cell. I would like to apply the data validation to each of the 10*3 = 30 cells. It is difficult to use this workaround as you did, and "rewrite" the formula on the data validation.